# How to generate a matrix based on a values of another matrix in R

Tags: r, matrix

Suppose that I have lower triangular matrix i.e.,

```
w1 <- c(0,0.6,0.3,0.6,0.7,
    0,0,0.6,0.6,0.7,
    0,0,0,0.6,0.6,
    0,0,0,0,0.7,
    0,0,0,0,0)
w1 <- matrix(w1,5,5)
```

Then, I would like the second matrix to be a lower triangular matrix, say `w2` where each non-zero values of `w2` are `1-the corresponding values of w1`.

Like this:

```
w2 <- c(0,0.4,0.7,0.4,0.3,
    0,0,0.4,0.4,0.3,
    0,0,0,0.4,0.4,
    0,0,0,0,0.3,
    0,0,0,0,0)
w2 <- matrix(w2,5,5) 
w <- list(w1, w2)
```

How can I get `w2` automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since most operations in R are vectorised, you can simply use `ifelse` to either subtract `1 - w1`, or if `w1` is zero, retain zero.

`ifelse(w1 == 0, 0, 1 - w1)`

Comment: amazing help. Thanks a lot.

Comment: No problem! There are a lot of neat tricks in R that definitely are not obvious starting off

Answer (score 1):

You can use the indexing of `lower.tri()` also on the left side:

```
w2new <- matrix(0, dim(w1)[1], dim(w1)[2])
w2new[lower.tri(w2new)] <- 1 - w1[lower.tri(w1)]
```